# Gitlab not processing markdown in comments in a java file

Tags: java, gitlab

In a Java file on GitLab, I see the following in the comments:
`<br>&lt;Configuration&gt;`
Not sure why GitLab is not parsing the markdown and displaying it properly.
Is there a way to do it?
or markdown things should not be in the comments in a Java file
Here is a minimal version of the file:

```
 package abc.xyz;
    
 import abc.util.SUtil; 
    /**
    *
    *<table border="1">
    *<tr> 
    *.
    *.
    *.
    **/
 public class XP {
    /** <br>&lt;Configuration&gt;
    *.
    *.
    **/
  void method(){
     }
    }
```

Here the markdown comments above the method explain what the method does.

Comment: Why do you expect GitLab to parse markdown in Java files? Can you share the relevant file?

Comment: @dan1st That's reasonable. What I am doing currently is copying the markdown comment and pasting it into some online markdown viewer to understand it which is inconvenient. I see some code written like that in my company. Not sure if this is a recommended practice or should be avoided?

Comment: That's not Markdown, that's plain ol' HTML. (But why would GitLab render HTML in a Java file? You want to see the source code, not the rendered or compiler version of it)

Comment: Do you expect a Javadoc viewer? You can use your IDE for that. Why do you think GitLab is supposed to do that?